# Call a reusable flow from existing Automated Cloud flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have an automated cloud flow which create 10 items inside 10 different lists. now for each item i want to set unique permission. so can i create a reusable flow which accept 2 parameters:

1. ItemID
2. Comma separated user string

Then to call this reusable flow 10 times inside my current automated cloud flow? instead of having to repeat the same logic 10 times inside the automated cloud flow?

Comment: Yes, you can [Call child flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows) in Power Automate. You will need list name, site URLs (if different), etc. as well in child flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call reusable power automate flow from your automated cloud flow. You need to create/add both flows in single solution.

Refer this Microsoft official documentation related to child flows: [Create child flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows)

You might also need list name, site URLs (if different), etc. as well in child/reusable flow.

---

I just tried the similar scenario and it works for me.

Parent flow:

[image]

Child flow:

[image]

---

**Additional Info**:

If you are using "Apply to each" action in parent/automate flow, you can also enable  concurrency from apply to each action settings to run actions inside parallelly.

[image]

Comment: so i will create one child record which contain the logic to set permissions, then i will create 10 parent flows which will call the child workflow. am i correct?

Comment: Yes correct, parent flows will call the child flow and child flow will have common logic to execute on data passed from parent flow.